# Making a server visible from the outside under VPN

Tags: vpn, internet, ip, webserver

I want to run GNU/Linux server with VPN that becomes visible to the internet, so e.g. if I run Apache and the public IP of the VPN is 12.34.56.78, then by accessing 12.34.56.78 I should see my website, in theory (or that's what I want).

Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking... could you re-word, and perhaps provide a diagram? Draw the two computers, and specify where you want to run the web server, where you want the ingress and how the VPN fits into it. (my take is quite different from @davidgo's)

Answer (score 0):

Its not clear where yoy envusage issues, but its entirely practical and easy to run an OpenVPN server snd web server on the same IP address - of-course, data going to that ewal IP address will not be sent over the VPN - there woukd generally be another set of addresses advertised over it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume by VPN you mean a public VPN provider like NordVPN or Private Internet Access. The problem you are going to find is that the public IP of the VPN is a shared IP among many VPN users. You need port forwarding, and getting a port forward on a public VPN is finicky if available at all. You will get a single high port number >10,000 that you have no control over. You won't be able to get the standard port 80/443 for http/https. The whole process is rather dirty and you end up accessing your website via a kludgy url like http://12.34.56.78:87654 where both the IP and port are dynamic and might change.

You will need to research how to request port forward for your specific VPN provider. The option may only be officially supported through your provider's VPN client software, which in turn may not be supported on Linux. You need to use a reverse engineered solution. PIA port forwarding can be done via a curl request. [PIA example](https://www.privateinternetaccess.com/archive/forum/discussion/180/port-forwarding-without-the-application-advanced-users)